# Solutions to inline filename content disposition and injecting a dynamic filename for saving action

Tags: .net, pdf, httphandler, content-disposition

Essentially I am streaming a pdf from memory to the user's browser. I would like to allow the system user to be able to hit save in adobe (in browser) and have the filename pre-filled with a dynamic value (e.g. last name of the customer).

I've read a bit about this problem so far, it seems that content disposition header setting the inline filename isn't implemented correctly.

I have read that adobe takes the filename from the page that generates the pdf. I.e. if the page name is pdfviewer.aspx, then the pre-filled value of the pdf's filename is pdfviewer.pdf.

I am looking for a work around. My original idea was for a http handler which will generate and push out the pdf, and have the web config as such:

```
 <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="Logic.PDFHandler" />
```

This way when I dynamically set the link to "lastname.ashx", it should run the code in PDFHandler, while the url will be somthing like "...\lastname.ashx". I seem to be able to get this to work in a proof of concept (substituting the generation of the pdf with a simple repsonse.write("hello world")), but I'm just wondering, if there are any better work arounds?

Note: The proof of concept only works in IE and I'm happy for it as it is the browser targeted for this intranet application.

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET routing would let you route `/GeneratePDF/{id}/{lastname}.pdf` or something to your handler.

Answer (score 0):

The way to make the browser ask you to save the PDF with a given name is as follows:

```
// code runs on ASP.NET server
Response.Clear();
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", string.Format("attachment; filename={0}".
   fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
// stream PDF to response object
```

Comment: This gives you a save dialog (with the filename prefilled), however, I am after a solution where the pdf is streamed (and opened) in the browser. Once open, adobe allows you to save the pdf, but takes the filename from the page not the header.

Comment: In that case, change 'attachment' into 'inline'.

Comment: Inline does not work in IE8. I'm pretty sure this is an existing bug.